# Loadable modules messages under Cygwin

Tags: dll, cygwin, shared-libraries, llvm

When building LLVM using cmake, a few components involving "Loadable modules" are not built, and warning messages such as the following are issued:

```
-- LLVMHello ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
...
-- BugpointPasses ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
...
-- SampleAnalyzerPlugin ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- PrintFunctionNames ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
```

But loadable modules *are* supported under Cygwin; and the handy `opt` tool can readily be used. Building with `./configure` produces no such messages; and the components are built. Why do these messages occur? Is there a way to build using cmake, and still have these components built?

Answer (score -1):

The loadable modules are not supported on Windows due to lack of dynamic linking on this platform. The plugins definitely should be disabled on autoconf build as well.

The only way to use loadable modules on windows is to build the whole LLVM into a big .DLL

Comment: Alas this is a common misunderstanding. As I said in my question, loadable modules *are* supported under Cygwin; and have been for years. Loadable modules are not supported under Visual Studio - often this is conflated with Windows. My question in fact relates only to the error messages, *when cmake is used*; using (again) configure produces no such messages. Note that those messages relate to the platform.