# LLVM out of source pass build: Loadable modules not supported (on Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, llvm

I compiled and installed LLVM from trunk on debian wheezy some weeks ago (configure & make) and now tried to out of source compile the [llvm-mutate pass](http://eschulte.github.io/llvm-mutate/).
AFAICC, llvm-mutate follows the cmake [out of source pass build instructions](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#developing-llvm-passes-out-of-source).

When trying to build llvm-mutate

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/local/share/llvm/cmake ../
```

I get:

-- Mutate ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.

hmm?
opt and the loadable passes (at llvm_trunk/build/Debug+Asserts/lib/xxx.so) are present and work (have been compiled using configure & make, not cmake).

So this problem seems to be related to cmake?
Someone else faced such problems, howver on Win using cygwin: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491275/loadable-modules-messages-under-cygwin)

Any idea?
Thx
Alex

Answer (score 2):

`AddLLVM` cmake module needs some prerequisites. Add to CMakeLists.txt:

```
# AddLLVM needs these
set(LLVM_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_INTDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/bin)
set(LLVM_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_INTDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/lib)

include(HandleLLVMOptions) # important: matches compiler flags to LLVM/Clang build
include(AddLLVM)
```

Some inspiration came from [this message](https://www.marc.info/?l=llvm-dev&m=142196366215513&w=2).

Answer (score 1):

*Adding to alexei's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33249846/3048763).*

You can lso add `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file prior to the `include(AddLLVM)` line and then having in your `PATH` the LLVM binary directory for `llvm-config`, 
invoke cmake as

```
CXX=clang++ cmake -DLLVM_DIR=$(llvm-config --prefix)/share/llvm/cmake ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness if someone will come across this error. This bug is meanwhile fixed in LLVM 3.8.0 so that you only have to include *AddLLVM* to build your plugin. The *HandleLLVMOption* include file is only helpful to get the right compiler flags as stated above in the post.